# Searching ASP.NET Core In-memory list

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, in-memory

Having a list stored in-memory in an ASP.NET Core Web API application. Now I want to search for a specific item in the list. If I understand the documentation correctly I've to do it the following way:

```
List<string> lst = cache.Get("myList");
if (lst.Contains("dog"))  ....;
```

Assume there are hundreds of concurrent requests, so that the list has to be copied internally hundreds of times concurrently.
Is it possible to get only a pointer to the in-memory list and do the search inside this list? Or is there another RAM-saving approach?

Comment: its a little complicate if you use more than one pool - or you use only one pool, then where the cache lives ? in a memory or in a file ?, where and how you change this list ? Do you change that list and at the same time try to search it ?

Comment: One in memory pointer can be a static value, but then if you have many pools ? if you need to change the list ?

Comment: The cache lives in the memory. And update will be triggered by a api from outside. A flag will indicate whether there is just running an update.